# Can't upload media from phonegap app

Tags: javascript, android, html, cordova, file-upload

I'm using Adobe phonegap build to make an app out of my blog. My domain has a submission form where users can submit images and other media.

I have tried uploading media through the form from my pc web browser as well as my phone web browser and it works fine.

However when I want to upload media from the phonegap app, it lets my browse images to upload, but **tapping an image does not upload it**, it just returns me to the 'select image' button. Uploading similarly from my phone's chrome browser works fine. How can I fix this so that I can upload media from phonegap app?

Here is my config.xml file
https://codeshare.io/MAIdc

And here is my index.HTML file 
https://codeshare.io/Tl7KK

I'm using codeshare because for some reason part of the code wasn't showing up.

edit: is there some plugin that I should/should not be using that I don't know about?

Comment: only the ones listed. What plugins did you have in mind?

Comment: @RuiZhe I have checked your `Config.xml` you should cross check with this `cordova-plugin-media 1.0.2-dev "Media"
cordova-plugin-media-capture 1.1.1-dev "Capture"` Make sure you have both this installed in your app.

Comment: @jaydroider Thanks for the reply, I updated my config file as you mentioned and added those plugins. The updated config file is in the post, but the problem still persists. I still cannot upload any media to insert into posts.

Comment: @RuiZhe Have you added needful js files on your index page pls check with this also. And could you shoot you logcat trace while uploading or selecting image what is happening.